# How to use case in db2 column select query

Tags: sql, select, db2

I have a table in which there is a varchar column `'someid'` and some timestamp columns:
`'date_1', ... , date_4` and `'xdate_1', ... , xdate_4`
 I am trying to select two of them depending on 'someid' value, but had no luck until now. I am sure that this is syntax, googling also didn't help as all the examples were similar to my query.

Heres what I'm trying to do:

```
select
  case
    when someid = 1 then date_1
    when someid = 2 then date_2
    when someid = 3 then date_3
    when someid = 4 then date_4
 ,case
    when someid = 1 then xdate_1
    when someid = 2 then xdate_2
    when someid = 3 then xdate_3
    when someid = 4 then xdate_4
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You forgot the `end`

```
select
  case
    when someid = 1 then date_1
    when someid = 2 then date_2
    when someid = 3 then date_3
    when someid = 4 then date_4
  end as col1
 ,case
    when someid = 1 then xdate_1
    when someid = 2 then xdate_2
    when someid = 3 then xdate_3
    when someid = 4 then xdate_4
  end as col2
from mytable;
```

Answer (score 0):

As a note, if `someid` is a character column, then you should use character comparisons:

```
select (case when someid = '1' then date_1
             when someid = '2' then date_2
             when someid = '3' then date_3
             when someid = '4' then date_4
         end),
        . . .
from mytable;
```